# How do you slice an array of a dynamic dimension in numba?

Tags: python, numba

I have a script that looks as following:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit
def test(v):
    n = 1
    if len(v.shape)>1:
        n = max(n,v.shape[1])
    return n
test(np.array([1,2]))
```

This works fine without the `njit` decorator, but when I use it like in my example I get the error message

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
tuple index out of range
During: typing of static-get-item at my_script.py (7)

File "my_script.py", line 7:
def test(v):
    <source elided>
        n = max(n,v.shape[1])
        ^
```

How can I rewrite this function to make it dynamically check the shape of my array?

Comment: The title and body of this question don't seem to have anything to do with each other.

Comment: In Numba, 2D arrays and 1D arrays are different types. The code is compiled for 1 type. There is no possible way to check the type at runtime once compiled since this is what makes Numba fast as opposed to CPython. That being said features like generated jit may fit your needs: you can adapt the input code based on the type. If you want to share the same code, then Numba is not the right tool.